# Android: How to show touch hotspots for my application?

Tags: android, onclick, click

I have a requirement to register click and touch events on my application, and when needed by clicking say a view 10 times, add a layer on top of the screen showing touch counts in the form of hotspots

Hotspots is like the area with most count would have red color, then the area with second most count will have orangish color, next one has greenish..so on and so forth.

How to go about this task?

Comment: Log the coordinates in an array? Check which coordinates hit the most/ fall adjacent - there you go?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: yes...having the data and just displaying the appropriate color after sorting the data. I wanted to know if there is some Android component or something else available which I could use.